# Effective way to update XMLListCollection

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, httpservice

I have the following code:

```
private var xmlC:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
private var httpS:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
private var xmlData:XML;
private var xmlDataList:XMLList;

protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    httpS.url = "data.xml";
    httpS.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHTTP);
    httpS.resultFormat="e4x";
    httpS.send();

    timer.start();
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateXMLC);
}

private function updateXMLC(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    xmlC.source = xmlDataList;
    httpS.send();
}

private function resultHTTP(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    xmlData = event.result as XML;
    xmlDataList = xmlData.dg.rows.row;
}
```

"data.xml" have 5000 lines, so I need to clean its traces whenever necessary. I have two problems that I found thanks to the profiling

1. Every time httpS.send() is called in the method updateXMLC, it calls URLLoader internally which keeps XML that is not needed anymore wandering in the memory without being garbage collected
2. is there a more effective way to update xmlC, whenever the XMLListCollection is updated, it seems that the previous value of XMLListCollection doesn't get garbage collected

Comment: I'm not clear what question you're trying to ask.  You aren't creating new XMLListCollection's; you're just reusing the same variable.  Without knowing how you're using or referencing the the data inside the XMLListCollection it's impossible to determine why it wouldn't be getting garbage collected.

Comment: That's the full code, when changing the source of the XMLListCollection, it seems that some listeners are attached with XMLNotifier.getInstance().watchXML, I think this is what might be causing the memory leak

Comment: You haven't provided a runnable code snippet, which leads me to the conclusion that there must be more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a bug in Flex framework:

- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-31920
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-15113
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-599
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-11244
- http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-11982

Answer (score 4):

I was skeptical/intrigued after looking at the code that there would be any memory leaks so I tested out your code for myself.

The code you posted isn't actually run able.  I just added the bare minimum to have it run like app tag and import statements (and a counter label to see when a http service cycle completes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"> 
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var xmlC:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
        private var httpS:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
        private var xmlData:XML;
        private var xmlDataList:XMLList;

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            httpS.url = "data.xml";
            httpS.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHTTP);
            httpS.resultFormat="e4x";
            httpS.send();

            timer.start();
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateXMLC);
        }

        private function updateXMLC(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            xmlC.source = xmlDataList;
            httpS.send();
        }

        private function resultHTTP(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            counter.text = Number(parseInt(counter.text,10)+1).toString(); 
            xmlData = event.result as XML;
            xmlDataList = xmlData.dg.rows.row;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Label id="counter" text="0" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" fontSize="72"/>
</mx:Application>
```

The good news is there aren't any memory leaks in your code.  There also aren't any loitering objects in profiler either.

The bad news is whatever else you're doing in your application (code that is not posted up here, omitted for whatever reason) - that is where you have a leak / loitering objects.

You can see for yourself in profiler of the attached code, that the memory doesn't increase after the first few cycles of the http service.  I.e. it doesn't continue grasp more memory over time.  (By the way, the XML file I'm pulling in is about 8000 rows, over 1MB).

If you'd like to post more code, happy to look further - but think this solves this mystery for now.  ;)

Here's some fixes for what your doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable] private var xmlC:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
        private var httpS:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
        private var xmlData:XML;
        private var xmlDataList:XMLList;
        private var serviceRunning : Boolean = false;
        private var currentData : String = '';

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            httpS.url = "data.xml";
            httpS.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHTTP);
            httpS.resultFormat="e4x";
            httpS.send();

            timer.start();
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateXMLC);
        }

        private function updateXMLC(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            xmlC.source = xmlDataList;
            if( !serviceRunning ){  // don't call for more data until 
                httpS.send();       // you've gotten back last call
            }
        }

        private function resultHTTP(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            // make sure we have differences before rebinding
            var newData : String = event.result as String;
            serviceRunning = false;
            counter.text = Number(parseInt(counter.text,10)+1).toString();
            if( newData !=  currentData ){
                xmlData = event.result as XML;
                currentData = newData;
                xmlDataList = xmlData.dg.rows.row;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Label id="counter" text="0" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" fontSize="72"/>
 </mx:Application>
```

Comment: In the original code, there is a databinding which causing the problem. The xmllist which is returned with every httpservice call is set as the dataprovider of a datagrid, which is transformed to XMLListCollection in the DataGrid. That's why I'm searching for a better way to update the xmllistcollection and use it directly as the dataprovider

Comment: If you can provide the code then I can see what is going on.  Right now you're just giving hints to the problem after the fact.  If you want help solving it, the please help by posting the code.

Comment: I added a datagrid to the example and bound the collection. There was still no memory leaks.  However, the main issue that you are likely running into is that 1) binding that much data into a datagrid is intensive. Using binding is not the problem, the fact you're doing it so frequently for no apparent reason is a problem. 2) Because the binding is so intensive, you end up having multiple send calls over time that back up.  This equals a sluggish and dismal user experience. I'll edit and add fixes for these issues.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly you are recovering your XML data from a file that's in the same folder as your SWF. If this is the case then what is most likely happening is that the XML file is being cached in your browser and it's returning the same cached version over and over again.

When dealing with these issues you can add a dummy URL variable that makes the browser think that the file you are retrieving is new and it forces it to recover the file again.

You can achieve this by doing something like this:

`httpS.url = "data.xml?random="+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);`

If this doesn't fix the problem then maybe it can be associated to not resetting the variables that hold the actual XML data. You can accomplish this by resetting with new instances of your variables:

```
xmlData = new XML();
xmlDataList = new XMLList();
xmlC = new XMLListCollection();
```

Or if what you want is to just reset the XMLListCollection you can try using the "refresh()" method that is included in all Lists in Flex.

Important note: If you are using data binding with any of these variables this can cause Flex to not garbage collect the data because it is being used somewhere.

Comment: I am already using the URL trick by using a variable nocache= which changes every time. I'm using databinding with xmllist as the dataprovider of a datagrid, which changes it to xmllistcollection in set dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take to request, receive and process the XML?  It sounds like it's a fairly big file, so if it's more than a second, you'll have multiple calls to the HTTPService happening concurrently (as I understand it, your current timer will try and fire off a request every second, regardless of whether the last one has returned).

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I doubt it.  If I'm right, and you only want to send a request after you've got the response from the last one, then you would probably be better off getting rid of the timer and its function, then changing the resultHTTP method to something like this:

```
private function resultHTTP(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    xmlData = event.result as XML;
    xmlC.source = xmlData.dg.rows.row;
    httpS.send();
}
```

Of course, you may want to put a delay on it starting each time:

```
    protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        httpS.url = "data.xml";
        httpS.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHTTP);
        httpS.resultFormat="e4x";

        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateXMLC);
    }

    private function updateXMLC(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        timer.stop();
        httpS.send();
    }

    private function resultHTTP(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        xmlData = event.result as XML;
        xmlC.source = xmlData.dg.rows.row;
        timer.start();
    }
```

Sorry if I've misunderstood the issue though...

Either way, you probably want to put some sort of faultHTTP function in as well, so it also restarts the timer (or does whatever you need to do) on HTTP errors.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that when I profile, when I check the loitering objects, which have not been garbage collected, I find that there is an internal call to the method URLLoader.toString(). This call is done when the result is returned, it converts the returned XML to a string<This keeps the XML in memory each time, and I don't know what to do to get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if the garbage collection wasn't happening because of the potentially overlapping/concurrent calls.  It's unlikely, but it's weird that it's even doing URLLoader.toString(), so how and why it garbage collects might be weird too.  When exactly does it do the URLLoader.toString()?  Does it do it if you remove or amend any of your code in the method?

Comment: Also, why are you even using two separate variables for this data?  Why don't you store straight in `xmlC` (a bit like my example), and get rid of `xmlDataList` completely?

Comment: The original code is a lot more complicated, and it needs an xmllist that will be filtered, and then it will be passed to xmllistcollection. I don't know neither why it calls URLLoader.toString.